# fetching last 3 rows in ascending order with t-sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CommentID   Name       Replies                             OrderID
313         Ed         dlfkndl sdknldgf dlffdg               496
313         James      sdsflsdf snflsf sfnslf sfnklsdf       499
313         Jeff       sdsflsdf snflsf sfnslf sfnklsdf       500
313         Alan       sdsflsdf snflsf sfnslf sfnklsdf       501
313         William    sdflksnfdlsk sdfknslnf slfnks         503
```

I have a sample table above which is in an ascending order by [OrderID]. I want to fetch the last
3 rows of the table which is in an ascending order as well which is shown below.

```
CommentID   Name       Replies                              OrderID
313         Jeff       sdsflsdf snflsf sfnslf sfnklsdf        500
313         Alan       sdsflsdf snflsf sfnslf sfnklsdf        501
313         William    sdflksnfdlsk sdfknslnf slfnks          503
```

What is the exact syntax to do this in T-SQL? Thanks...
I tried to come up with this but still not not fetching the last 3 rows in an asc order.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [RepTab] WHERE [OrderID] > (SELECT MAX([OrderID]) - 3 FROM [RepTab] WHERE [CommentID]='" + Id + "') ", con);
```

Comment: I tried something like this SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [RepTab] WHERE [OrderID] > (SELECT MAX([OrderID]) - 3 FROM [RepTab] WHERE [CommentID]='" + Id + "') ", con); but it won't give the last 3 rows in asc order..Thnks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write the query using `Common Table Expression` as:

```
With CTE as
( select row_number() over ( partition by CommentID order by OrderID desc) as rownum,
         CommentID,
         Name,
         Replies,
         OrderID
  From reptab
 ) 
 select  CommentID,
         Name,
         Replies,
         OrderID
 from CTE 
 where rownum <=3
 and CommentID = 313
 order by OrderID asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the bottom 3 records in a subquery ordered descending, then order the outer ascending.

```
Select *
from
  (select top 3 orderid, commentid, replies, name
   From
     [RepTab] 
   Order by orderid desc
   ) t
Order by order id
```

### [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93692/1)

Comment: using the code I got a runtime error saying Incorrect syntax near 'Limit'.

Comment: Here's my code Select * From (select Replies, Name From [RepTab] Order by OrderID desc Limit 3) Order by OrderID

Comment: Are you using MySQL (as you have tagged your post) or MSSQL?

Comment: What did I miss? Thanks

Comment: mssql uses `top` instead of `limit`.   Try with the new edit @timmack

Comment: Also, please use the fields as I have set them.  If you remove order id from the inner query , you cannot order by it in the outer query.

Comment: That is my updated syntax based on the syntax you gave me on your answer

Comment: That was my mistake... top goes after select

Comment: Again it appears that you have removed order id from the inner query

Comment: No I don't think I removed the OrderID from my inner query.Take a look. Basing your new updated syntax using this code Select * From (select top 3 Replies, Name From [RepTab] Order by OrderID desc ) Order by OrderID  I got another runtime error saying Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'. Please double check.Thankns

Comment: @timmack do you see the query and understand?

Comment: @paqogomex Yes I'm watching closely with your codes and the fiddle is working fine but where is the WHERE clause on your syntax?How do I implement the WHERE on this because I'm querying the exact CommentID which 313 because there are other some CommentID values like 312, 314 or 309.

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to specify it on my post that I need to query the specific commentID using the WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query :

In above query paqogomez missed the table alias

```
Select *
from
  (select top 3 orderid, commentid, replies, name
   From
     [RepTab] 
   Order by orderid desc
   ) as tbl
Order by orderid
```

Comment: Thank you, a comment would have been a bit more professional however